# How to format Base64 encoded string while sending in JSON

Tags: javascript, java, groovy, base64, string-formatting

I want to format base64 encoded string, when I send the below string in JSON request - I am getting JSON validation error because this string is not formatted properly. I couldn't find any good utility which converts from base64 encoded string to the proper one.

Is there any utility in Java/Groovy or Javascript to format in a single line.

Appreciated your help

```
{
    "data": "JVBERi0xLjMNJeLjz9MNCjcgMCBvYmoNPDwvTGluZWFyaXplZCAxL0wgNzk0NS9PIDkvRSAzNTI0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"
}
```

Comment: You can use this regex to remove spaces, newlines from the string in JS: `/\s+/g` and replace with `""`

Answer (score 2):

```
// if this is your Base64 encoded string
var str = 'VGhpcyBpcyBhbiBhd2Vzb21lIHNjcmlwdA=='; 

// make URL friendly:
str = str.replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/\=+$/, '');

// reverse to original encoding
str = (str + '===').slice(0, str.length + (str.length % 4));
str = str.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
```

If By Formatting what you mean is making it URL friendly, Above Goes the Code!

If you are referring to encoding and decoding of the String,

You can use [btoa()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa) and [atob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob) to convert to and from base64 encoding

Comment: I think that he just wants to make a valid JSON.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood well you have problems to make a valid JSON with an base64 string.

I would recommend this: 
Use the JavaScript function 
`JSON.stringify(encodedData)`  which returns an escaped string that you can use it with no problems in your JSON afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

The encoded data is a PDF file, so it is binary data and you should not attempt to convert it to a String.

Instead, deal with the Bytes, for instance, by writing it to a file. In Groovy:

```
// String s = <your JSON>

Byte[] b = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(s) // no errors here, the JSON  you supplied is valid
 ."data" // GPath syntax for getting the "data" element in the JSON
 .replaceAll (/\s/, "") // remove spaces and newlines
 .decodeBase64() // returns an array of Byte

new File("somefile.pdf").bytes = b
```

Opening somefile.pdf, I can see:

`Adobe Acrobat PDF Files
Adobe Portable Document Format (PDF) is a universal file format that preserves allof the fonts, formatting, colours and graphics of any source document, regardless ofthe application and platform used to create it.
...`

If the encoded data had in fact been a String, you could get the original String just by `String x = new String(b)`.